# LDAP userPassword encryption?

Tags: openldap

When I use ldapsearch command, I see my password (is 'abc123') is encrypted in openldap:

> userPassword:: e1NTSEF9THk4YmtNTUxHV09sOEYvdUdKRE1McFR6eTU2OWNQRVo=

I tried to encode my password on http://www.onlinehashcrack.com/hash-calculator.php but cannot see matched method.

Could you show me what is encryption method here or how to find it in openldap configuration?

Thanks,

Viet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "=" on the end suggests that the password is base64 encoded. Once the base64 is decoded you will see:

```
{SSHA}Ly8bkMMLGWOl8F/uGJDMLpTzy569cPEZ
```

This means your password is stored as a SHA1 with salt. The actual hash is encoded in base64 again after `{SSHA}`.

See http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/347.html for details about generating a new salted SHA1.

Comment: Actually the two colons in `userPassword::` indicate that the attribute value is base64 encoded, not the `=`. A base64 encoded string doesn't necessarily contain a `=` at the end (or anywhere).

Comment: good point @daff, I didn't know that :) It only suggested to me that it was base64 encoded :)